# React Typescript generics - Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

Pretty sure I am missing a key concept here, but not able to figure out what.

I have a React component `HorizontalSelector` whose props are of type `SelectorProps<T>` defined by,

```
interface SelectorProps<T> {
  convert: (value: T[]) => T[];
}
```

I am consuming the component as follows.

```
...

export function kgsToLbs(value: number[]): number[] {
  const ONE_KG_IN_POUNDS = 2.20462;
  return value.map(val => val / ONE_KG_IN_POUNDS);
}

const props:SelectorProps<number> = {
  convert: kgsToLbs
}

<HorizontalSelector {...props}>

...
```

unfortunately I get this error

```
Type '{ calculate: (value: number[]) => number[]; }' is not assignable to type 'HorizontalSelectorProps<unknown>'.
  Types of property 'calculate' are incompatible.
    Type '(value: number[]) => number[]' is not assignable to type '(value: unknown[]) => unknown[]'.
      Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Don't know what to make of it. If anyone can help me understand the reasonsing behind this error, it'll be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide an online demo? Which may help others to catch up with the problem you are facing quickly.

Comment: it would be good to see `HorizontalSelector`. You have an extra `}` in your example, perhaps a typo?

Comment: Is `HorizontalSelector` generic?

Comment: I would love to add a snippet example, but both in codepen and typescript playground, it seems to work as expected.